# Using comboBox auto complete to suggest from list of custom class

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, autocomplete

I have a class like this:

```
public class Region
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Abbreviation { get; set; }
    public string Area { get; set; }
    public string Picture { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
}
```

and I have a comboBox where I have set the items like this:

```
//where regions is a List<Region>
comboBox.DataSource = regions;
comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";
```

When the user manually enters text in the comboBox, I would like to suggest some Regions where `Region.Name.Contains(comboBox.Text)`. How do I go about accomplishing this?

Comment: Do you mean Region.DisplayName.Contains(comboBox.Text)? Wouldn't it be confusing to the user to search based on Name instead of DisplayName

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you are looking for, but If you want to do by `Region.DisplayName.Contains(comboBox.Text)` then the following code can accomplish it.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    List<Region> _regions = new List<Region>();
    public Form1()
    {
        //Some data to test with
        _regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "AA", DisplayName = "11" });
        _regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "AAAA", DisplayName = "111" });
        _regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "AAAAA", DisplayName = "1111" });
        _regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "BBBBBB", DisplayName = "22222" });
        _regions.Add(new Region() { Name = "CCCCC", DisplayName = "333333" });
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox.AutoCompleteMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
        comboBox.AutoCompleteSource = System.Windows.Forms.AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
        comboBox.DataSource = _regions;
        comboBox.DisplayMember = "DisplayName";

        var autoCompleteCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
        if (_regions != null && _regions.Count() > 0)
            foreach (Region region in _regions)
                autoCompleteCollection.Add(region.DisplayName);

        comboBox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = autoCompleteCollection;
    }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to suggest based on if the DisplayName "contains" the comboBox.Text but rather if the DisplayName "starts with" the comboBox.Text